# How to sum a single row with multiple columns in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linq-query-syntax

```
 (from item in _dbEntities.Bills
             where item.Year == year
             select item).GroupBy(x => x.MonthID).Sum(x => x.Phone);
```

I want to sum all utility bills month wise like January there are 4 bills electricity, phone, water,gas.. these are in a single row in table how to get sum of these all and groupby monthID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this. :

```
var result= _dbEntities.Bills.Where(b => b.Year == year)
                             .GroupBy(b => b.MonthId)
                             .Select(g=> new { MonthId=g.Key,
                                               Phone=g.Sum(b=>b.Phone),
                                               Water = g.Sum(b => b.Water),
                                               Gas = g.Sum(b => b.Gas),
                                               Electricity = g.Sum(b => b.Electricity)                                         
                                             }).ToList();
```

I save the result in a anonymous type with five properties, the first one to save the `MonthId`, and the rest to save the sum of all the services in that particular month.

Comment: it returns a query i want a list or dictionary type so i can view data

Comment: well, you can call the `ToList` method or `ToDictionary` method at the end of the query.

Comment: but there is one other issue while calling these extension methods i am converting those all fields to int using int.parse(b.Phone) etc because they are in string format so when i use tolist or dictionary it gives the convert.toint32() error

Comment: "Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: I understand what is your problem. Linq to Entities doesn't support that operation. At the end, your query will be translated to sql, that's way that operation is not allowed. After the `GroupBy` try to call the `AsEnumerable` method and after that apply the `Select`

Comment: could you please show the query that you are trying to execute?

Comment: it works you are right I just applied asenumerable before int.parse and it works thanks buddy

Comment: You welcome,BTW if you want to work with money I suggest you use the `decimal` type instead `int`

Answer (score 1):

This one return you total sum of all bills for each month (two fileds **MonthID**, **Total**):

```
var result = items.Where(b => b.Year == year)
    .Select(b => new { b.MonthID, Total = b.Electricity + b.Gas + b.Phone + b.Water })
    .GroupBy(b => b.MonthID)
    .Select(g => new { MonthID = g.Key, Total = g.Sum(i => i.Total) });
```

And this one return sum of each bill for each month (five fields: **MonthID**, **TotalElectricity**, **TotalPhone**, **TotalWater**, **TotalGas**):

```
var result = items.Where(b => b.Year == year)
    .GroupBy(b => b.MonthID)
    .Select(
        g => new {
            MonthID = g.Key,
            TotalElectricity = g.Sum(b => b.Electricity),
            TotalPhone = g.Sum(b => b.Phone),
            TotalWater = g.Sum(b => b.Water),
            TotalGas = g.Sum(b => b.Gas)
        }
    );
```

Comment: it returns a query i want a list or dictionary type so i can view data

Comment: Add .ToList() or ToDictionary() at the end of expression.